# Find the number of roots of following equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $a$ is a real number,the number of roots of $\cot x- \tan x = a$ in the first quadrants.

Comment: You have asked more than 20 questions on this site. However, yo do not seem to show any effort on your part. This is not a 'Someone does your HomeWork' site. Certainly someone will help you if you show efforts.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$a=\cot x-\tan x=\cdots=2\cot2x$$

$$\implies\cot2x=\dfrac a2$$

$$\implies2x=n\pi+\text{arccot}\dfrac a2$$

Answer (score 1):

I have inserted image below please view it. [image]

Comment: Can you give a source for this image? If it's from a book, can you cite it, please? If you wrote it, can you just copy the tex here?